# Was there evil / darkness before god created everything?

Tags: good-and-evil

When god created everything, the `light` was shining on `darkness` and the "darkness" never mastered it. The tree of knowledge of good and evil was also there when god created everything.  The serpent acted against the will of God and which is supposed to be a lesser creation than the humans as envisaged by God.

How come God allowed a serpent cheat humans which God created in His own image and likeness?

Could there be a force against the will of God?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I invite you to read the faq and also a few of the questions here to get a good idea for the acceptable format for this site. You question currently is too open ended and may invite argument. Also you have two completely different questions in the end of the body. They all have high potential. I would suggest that you edit it to narrow down the scope of the answer you envision. I have alerted a long time user that should be able to help more.

Comment: @Alypius I think the op intends to ask about darkness symbolically not realistically.

Comment: I'm not sure that it would be a answer but I think that the evil is a result of the lack of good, since there was only God(good) there was no evil and that leads us to think that God(good) is absolute. Evil is not absolute, it exists because of the absence of good. I think God always knew the result of that, the "risk involved"

Comment: If you changed this question to 'what is the origin of evil' it would be a great question. I am not sure if someone has asked it yet.  The questions as it stands now is just a question that serves as an introduction of one theory not popular at all in Christianity- that evil existed before God made creation.

Comment: As a new user I want you to know that a closed question is not a bad thing. It only means that answers for it cannot be submitted. The community can vote to reopen your question, but likely no one will unless you take some of the suggestions above. Ping us in a comment here with @username to let us know you have changed it.